# How to make a group by selecting the specific data with crossfilter.js?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

How to make a group by selecting the specific data with crossfilter.js?

```
var xf = crossfilter(csv);
var yearAppliedDim = xf.dimension(function(d) {
            return d.yearApplied;
});
var apply15 = yearAppliedDim.group().reduceCount(function(d) {return d.yearApplied == 2009 }); //<-it doesn't work.
```

I want to count how many datas which yearApplied=2009.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a JSFiddle or something similar using example data.

You should get a list of groups counts by year if you change your last line to

```
yearAppliedDim.group().top(Infinity);
```

Then find the relevant group (where key is '2009') and you should have your count.